# How to run cross in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, cross-compiling

I want to cross-compile a rust project in a `Dockerfile`. I want to run on a x86-64 system and run `docker buildx build -t my-image . --platform linux/arm64`, with a `Dockerfile` that copies the Rust sources into the build and runs `RUN cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release`.
I tried:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 rust:1.68-slim as base

ENV CROSS_CONTAINER_IN_CONTAINER=true
RUN cargo install cross --git https://github.com/cross-rs/cross
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

ENV CARGO_TARGET_DIR=/build
RUN cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release

FROM debian:stable-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /build/my-app .

CMD ["./my-app"]
```

But I get

```
 => ERROR [base 7/7] RUN cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.0s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [base 7/7] RUN cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#0 0.903 Error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#0 0.903    0: no container engine found
#0 0.903 
#0 0.903 Suggestion: is docker or podman installed?
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release]: exit code: 1
```

[cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross) has [instructions on running in a container](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross#docker-in-docker), but the instructions are for running in an already built container, not for during the build. They include mounting the docker socket of the host, but I don't see how to mount volumes when running `docker buildx build ...`.

So how to cross compile a Rust project with [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross) as part of a docker build?

Answer (score 1):

Install docker CLI `RUN apt update && apt install -y docker.io`

`cross` internally calls `docker --help` to determine the engine type so the docker or podman binary must be installed.